# Unexpected character (at character 1) E/flutter ( 5156): <!doctype html>

Tags: json, flutter, google-signin

I am getting an error when the app start and also when I try to google sign in in a flutter app, api code like below ;

---

app starting

```
  Future<UserNotifications> getNotificationList(
      String start, String limit) async {
    client = http.Client();
    print(SessionManager.accessToken);
    final response = await client.post(
      Uri.parse(Const.getNotificationList),
      body: {
        Const.start: start,
        Const.limit: limit,
      },
      headers: {
        Const.uniqueKey: apiKey,
        Const.authorization: SessionManager.accessToken,
      },
    );
    print(response.body);
    final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);**
    return UserNotifications.fromJson(responseJson);
  }
```

---

when try to sign in with google

```
 class ApiService {
      var client = http.Client();
      final apiKey = 'xxxx';
    
      Future<User> registerUser(HashMap<String, String> params) async {
        final response = await client.post(
          Uri.parse(Const.registerUser),
          body: params,
          headers: {Const.uniqueKey: apiKey},
        );
        **final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);**
        SessionManager sessionManager = SessionManager();
        await sessionManager.initPref();
        print(jsonEncode(User.fromJson(responseJson)));
        sessionManager.saveUser(jsonEncode(User.fromJson(responseJson)));
        return User.fromJson(responseJson);
      }
```

Error like ;

```
E/flutter ( 5156): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 5156): <!doctype html>
E/flutter ( 5156): ^
E/flutter ( 5156):
E/flutter ( 5156): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
E/flutter ( 5156): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)
E/flutter ( 5156): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)
E/flutter ( 5156): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
E/flutter ( 5156): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
```

[image]

Comment: Check which route you call and what the result is with Postman

Comment: It seems that you get an html response instead of a JSON response. That's why Flutter is not able to decode the response body.

Comment: You unconditionally call `jsonDecode` on `response.body` without first checking `response.statusCode` to see if your request succeeded.  Most likely your request failed and you're receiving an HTML error page.